# PC doesn't boot after power-on, but does after reset

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I've got a pc based on a gigabyte ga-p35-ds3p motherboard with a weird boot problem.

The machine was working perfectly but after being in storage for about 6 weeks it fails to boot correctly immediately after power up.  It "ticks" the speaker a few times then beeps (perhaps a couple of times very quickly) then does nothing and the monitor goes into "no signal detected" mode.  If I hit reset it then boots perfectly normally.

I've tried playing with various BIOS settings including Halt On to "No Errors", but no difference.

What would cause first boot after power on to fail, but work after reset?

Answer (score 2):

Try a hard reset, power off the PC, remove the power cord and hold the power button in for 30 seconds, connect power cord, see if it boots properly now.

If this does not help, power down and remove power cord, hold the power button in for 15 seconds, [consult your motherboard manual](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2625#manual) and use the motherboard clr_cmos jumper to reset the cmos.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but it didn't help.  Made no difference at all.